Where do I put the Disposable for RxJava?
I'm using RxJava2 and subscribing to my data streams with a CompositeDisposable variable. I'm familiar with codebases having the disposable in the Fragment/Activity, but I'm not entirely sure why that is.
I suppose it's to take advantage of the Android lifecycle i.e. so that disposables are cleared in onDestroy, but could (or rather, should) the disposable be stored elsewhere? Like in a view model perhaps? And can these other places, if any, achieve the same effect as if the disposable were in a Fragment/Activity?
I know there's nothing stopping from doing so, but I'm more concerned about what's the best practice.

The disposable should be local to whatever is doing the subscribing.  That could be an Activity or Fragment if that's how your architecture makes sense.  It could also be someplace totally different.  The question is too vague to give a more solid answer.  The answer for where it should be saved and when you subscribe/unsubscribe is going to be different for every piece of data/reason you subscribe.

I believe https://github.com/sellmair/disposer can achieve what I'm thinking of. By using a LifecycleOwner then the API can hook onto lifecycle events to, in my case, dispose disposables.
